# JSON Interation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to show results from my JSON data in sets of 10. This pulls the entire list in set :

```
function populateSavedData(select, data) {
  var items = [];

 $.each(data, function (id, option) {

items.push('<li><div class="slider-product"><img class="slider-product-img" src="' +   
option.product_image_url + '"/><div  class="buy-it"><a href="'  + option.exit_url + '"><img 
src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/v5cache/TBS/images/shows/cougartown/buy-it-button.png?" border="0">
</a></div><div class="product-info">'+ option.product_name + '</div></div></li>');
});  
select.html(items.join(''));
}
populateSavedData($('ul'), json);
```

How would I change this to show me a set of the first 10 in one div, and a set of the second 10 in another div? I am new to both js and json.

Here is my JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/graphicallychallenged/D699t/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
select.html(items.join(''));
```

do

```
while (items.length) {
    var group = items.splice(0, Math.min(10, items.length)); //take 10 items if there are more
    var $div = getDiv(); //get the div where we want to insert the items
    $div.html(group.join(''));
}
```

You'll have to implement the *getDiv()* function, which returns the nest div (or element) into which you want to insert the elements.

*Array.splice* takes returns a slice or an array, modifying the original array. Basically, I'm taking 10 items from the beginning of the array in each iteration, until there are none left.

Comment: Can you edit your post? It's very hard to understand your code in a comment.

Comment: I added a JS Fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this along the following lines (caveat, not tested, but the principal is sound):

```
var cnt = 0;
$.each(data, function (id, option) {
  if(cnt++ % 10 === 0) {
    if(items.length) items.push('</div>');
    items.push('<div>');
  }
  items.push('...');
});  
select.html(items.join(''));
```

BTW, your LI tags are pretty busy, with a lot of structural noise.  You should be able to simplify this to something more along the lines of:

```
<li><a>...</a></li>
```

and loose all those pesky DIVs (i.e., your current code suffers a bit from [divitis](http://csscreator.com/divitis)